# .NET 5 issue on "old" arm64 / how to publish for arm64/gcc4.x

Tags: arm, cross-compilation, compatibility, .net

#### Background

I'm having more success than expected running binaries from a (relatively simple) `C#` program on "antiquated" `arm` and `arm64` systems built on `linux-x64` and published with `RID`s `linux-arm` and `linux-arm64`.

On one machine I get the following, however: `symbol _ZTTNSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference`

According to some information I found, the reason is that from `gcc-5` onward, the `c++` ABI has changed. Indeed this system is a `glibc-2.20` compiled with `gcc-4.9.4`.

#### My questions:

- is there any already available `RID` which publishes binaries known to be compatible with `gcc-4.9` on `arm64` (all `RID`s are [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/src/runtime.json))? (I've tried some of "the oldest" I could find from the list, that support `arm64`, but none worked).
- if not, would it be feasible to build the SDK in e.g. a `wheezy arm64` container (I've had success with this compiling for `glibc-2.19` compatibility).
- if I have a custom-build cross-SDK, how can I add a `RID` so I can use it in the standard `dotnet publish` workflow? (I build on `linux-x64` for `linux-arm*`)

Comment: Small update: by bundling a custom `libstdc++.so.6` (crossbuilt as necessary in a foreign-arch native container) as native lib with the dotnet app, the error can be worked around. It still does not address a completely transparent publish workflow though.